# Does the "published" field of the Blogger API v3 accept dates in the past?

Tags: api, google-api, blogger

I'm working on a python script that will move my markdown posts from Octopress/Jekyll to Blogger.com.

I can create posts using the insert function but so far I've been unsuccessful in creating posts with a published value in the past. Providing a date in the past results in the current datetime timestamp. I can create posts in the future which show up on rjmolesa-test.blogspot.com as scheduled posts.

I want them to post with their original post date and time. I can edit a post in blogger and manually set the value to one in the past without issue. But having to do it manually completely negates my purpose of writing a script to handle the conversion for me.

The date format follows RFC3339 and looks similar to 2012-07-31T08:21:00-04:00. I am on the east coast which is currently EDT.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having similar problems with Blogger API v3 in Java.  And the Javascript powered API explorer has similar issues.

It seems that this is a read-only field in V3.  And according to one of the Google engineers, it is a feature enhancement to make this field editable.

Note that using the the Blogger API v2, I was able to modify the published date.  However, this version has the problem in which the labels cannot be set (using the Java API).